# Rally sorting by Parent

Tags: sorting, rally

**What I Need**

I would like to sort my grid/store by the Parent field, but because the Parent field that is fetched is an object, it fails to fetch any records when I put a sorter based on the Parent property.  Even if I add a sorter function, it is not called.  I am using a rallygrid, not sure if that makes a difference

```
sorters: [{
    property: 'Parent',
    direction: 'DESC',
    sorterFn: function(one, two) {
        console.log('one',one);
        console.log('two',two); // console never shows these
        return -1;
    }
}]
```

**What I have tried**

To get around displaying the object, I have added a renderer function to the Parent column.  I tried adding a doSort to the column, and that function is called, but sorting the store does not call my sorterFn, it only uses the property and direction (similar to the console.log() that fails to run above)

Comment: So it looks like a rally grid using a wsapidatastore cannot do something like this - wsapidatastore does not have all of the functionality of a normal Ext.data.store (because it is a Pageable store), like defining sorters as Ext.util.Sorter.  I want the functionality of a rallygrid though - I want inline edit by default, and the other nice features it adds.  Am I missing some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess the question becomes, if you specify a model to a rallygrid, is it using a wsapidatastore to populate the grid?  My inablity to filter makes me think so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a custom App that works properly.  The key is setting the default storeConfig of remoteSort to false!

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        App = this;
        Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
             type: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
             success: function(model) {
                 App.add({
                     xtype: 'rallygrid',
                     id   : 'grid',
                     model: model,
                     columnCfgs: [
                         'FormattedID',
                         'Name',
                         {dataIndex: 'Parent', name: 'Parent', 
                            doSort: function(state) {
                                var ds = this.up('grid').getStore();
                                var field = this.getSortParam();
                                console.log('field',field);
                                ds.sort({
                                    property: field,
                                    direction: state,
                                    sorterFn: function(v1, v2){

                                        v1 = v1.get(field);
                                        v2 = v2.get(field);
                                        console.log('v1',v1);
                                        console.log('v2',v2);
                                        if (!v1 && !v2) {
                                            return 0;
                                        } else if (!v2) {
                                            return 1;
                                        } else if (!v1) {
                                            return -1;
                                        }
                                        return v1.Name.localeCompare(v2.Name);
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
                                var ret = record.raw.Parent;
                                if (ret) {
                                    return ret.Name;
                                } else {
                                    return record.data.Name;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    storeConfig: {
                        remoteSort: false
                    }
                 });
             }
         });
    }
});
```